# SQL Joining tables but getting skipped values

Tags: sql, join, skip

Hi i have joined to tables the code is below. Notice I have used A.Manad = B.Manad which joins data where the month of table A and B is equal. But sometimes table B dont have any data for that month. My code just skip the data, i would rather it just leave it empty or with a value of 0.

The Code takes a list of Orgnr which is swedish for company numbers and joins two tables where the orgnr is the same and the month is the same, but for some reason it doesnt join the data when the value is empty for one company. I still want the orgnr to show up in the joint table.

```
select Tillnr = A.tillnr, Orgnr = A.orgnr, Månad = A.Manad, Intrastat = 
A.varde,Moms = B.vardeutf
into #Tabell1 
From
    IntrastatFsum A
    left outer join
    Momsuppg B
        on A.Orgnr = B.Orgnr
where A.Orgnr in(
165563137933,165020456017,.......)
AND A.Ar = 2017
AND B.Ar = A.AR
AND A.Manad = 9
AND A.Manad = B.Manad
AND A.InfUtf = 'U'
```

Comment: You need to move the `AND B.Ar = A.AR AND A.Manad = B.Manad` into the join condition of the outer join

Answer (score 0):

You should move your `WHERE` clause `AND A.Manad = B.Manad` and `AND B.Ar = A.AR` to the `LEFT JOIN` clause.
In this way you will preserve all data from table `IntrastatFsum`:

```
select Tillnr = A.tillnr, Orgnr = A.orgnr, Månad = A.Manad, Intrastat = 
A.varde,Moms = B.vardeutf
into #Tabell1 
From
    IntrastatFsum A
    left outer join
    Momsuppg B
        on A.Orgnr = B.Orgnr
       AND A.Manad = B.Manad
       AND A.AR = B.Ar
where A.Orgnr in(
165563137933,165020456017,.......)
AND A.Ar = 2017
AND A.Manad = 9
AND A.InfUtf = 'U'
```